# Why signal function is not able to call my signal Handler?

Tags: fork, ipc

Here I have written a signal handler function named as `handler`
Correspondingly  this handler is registered to kernel using the signal function that will be invoked when `SIGCHLD` signal is generated by my child process.
Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void handler(int sig){
    pid_t pid;
    printf("The name of the PID=%d\n",getpid());
    pid=wait(NULL);
    printf("Pid %d exited \n",pid);
}
int main(){
    signal(SIGCHLD,handler)

    if(!fork()){
        printf("This is the child process %d\n",getpid());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Parent pid is %d\n",getpid());
    printf("The parent is waiting");
    return 0;

}
```

The output is :

```
Parent pid is 4356
The parent is waitingThis is the child process 4357
```

my question is why the handler is not called even though i have used the signal fucntion to regsiter my handler fucntion.This happens only when my handler is not registered.Why ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "the parent is waiting", and it is for a few cycles, but then you do "return 0", causing it to exit. If you want to receive the SIGCHLD, you need to ensure your parent doesn't exit before the child does its thing.

Easiest way to do this: insert a line before your `return 0`:

```
sleep(10);
```

which will cause your parent to wait for up to 10 seconds.

You will note that your parent *doesn't* actually wait for 10 seconds. The reason why is left as an exercise to the reader (hint: read the man page ;-)

Comment: but I read somewhere that even after the parent process exits it is not completely dead.

Comment: it is true that a process is not removed from the process table until its parent (or, if the parent has exited already, `init`) has called `wait()` on that process. However, at this point it is a zombie process, unable to do anything anymore. It certainly won't be able to receive and process signals anymore.

Comment: You could also use the `pause()` system call instead of `sleep()`, to allow time to do a few `ps -ef` and check PID -> PPID relationships without hurry.

Comment: @Kalu - if you had your child process doing a `getppid()` system call, you might catch PID 1 as the parent PID, if the forking process exits fast enough, and the kernel's scheduler cooperates.